# How to use OWIN in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, owin, azure-functions

We have a an API built using WebAPI and OWIN. Now this means that a lot of the authentication code uses OWIN classes, most of all the OwinContext, but when converting to running in Azure Functions, you're basically reduced to being a console app receiving a HttpRequestMessage.

In order to not have to reimplement our entire authorization/authentication scheme, is there any way to use OWIN in Azure Functions? Maybe by manually creating an OwinContext or something?

I'm sorry if this question is too broad, but I can't seem to fit my head around this.

Comment: Do you happen to use JWT for authentication?

Comment: We do for our Bearer tokens, yes. Any insights?

Comment: I don't have personal experience setting up an OWIN pipeline inside of an Azure Function. The code snippet posted by Amor looks interesting. However, validating JWTs is a relatively simple task so you could easily move that out of OWIN and into a utility library that you invoke in your function if the main concern is porting your Auth layer.

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe by manually creating an OwinContext or something?

Yes, we can manually create it according the request message. Based on the [protocol of OWIN](http://owin.org/html/spec/owin-1.0.html), we need to add the required keys to Environment dictionary. Sample code below is for your reference.

```
Dictionary<string, object> environment = new Dictionary<string, object>();

MemoryStream requestBody = new MemoryStream();
byte[] json = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ 'a' : 'value1' }");
requestBody.Write(json, 0, json.Length);
environment.Add("owin.RequestBody", requestBody);
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
headers.Add("host",new string[] { "myhost.com" });
headers.Add("Content-Type", new string[] { "application/json" });
environment.Add("owin.RequestHeaders", headers);
environment.Add("owin.RequestMethod", "POST");
environment.Add("owin.RequestPath", "a.html");
environment.Add("owin.RequestPathBase", "/");
environment.Add("owin.RequestProtocol", "HTTP/1.1");
environment.Add("owin.RequestQueryString", "myhost.com");
environment.Add("owin.RequestScheme", "http");

OwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);

context.Environment.Add("owin.ResponseHeaders", new Dictionary<string, string[]>());
context.Environment.Add("owin.ResponseBody", new MemoryStream());
```

Comment: Any updates? If you have further questions related to this topic, please feel free to let me know.